# When asking/answering a question on this site; Is there a way to fix the page in place so that you only see the displayed output as you type?

Tags: support, feature-request, markdown-preview, editor, user-scripts

I am a touch typist and would like to know if there exists a way to type a question\answer with all the necessary formatting without the page automatically scrolling back up to where you input the code with each successive keystroke?

There must be a way to dis-engage this annoying auto-scroll feature so that I can only see the rendered output as I type.

This is the simplest way I can think to word this question; if it is unclear to anyone what I'm asking then please let me know and I will elaborate.

Many thanks,

BLAZE.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea what I am asking here? There must be other touch typists that use this site that are sick of being automatically scrolled back up to the input box each type a key is pressed.

Comment: I suspect that this is a feature of browsers rather than of the site - if I type into a text box on *any* site, my browser scrolls to the box.

Comment: @Milo Yes, you're right; I have checked online looking for a way to override this with no such luck. But with the SE sites in particular it is a total nuisance having to hit page down every-time you want to see if what you've input renders correctly.

Comment: I guess you are aware of this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10505/feature-request-but-it-woudnt-be-a-feature-itd-be-a-blessing-editing-pane (Which is not the same as you want, but at least it is feature request in a similar direction.)

Comment: @Martin Thanks, shamefully I was not aware, but that is something that would certainly be the next best thing to what I am asking for.

Comment: If you write such long posts that it becomes a nuisance, I suggest using something like stackedit for example.

Comment: Since @NajibIdrissi mentioned StackEdit (which is, in my opinion, a very reasonable suggestion), I will add some older discussions, where this editor and some similar programs have been mentioned: [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/mathjax-better-way-to-prepare-a-math-stackexchange-question) and [MathJax WYSIWYG Editor](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12967/mathjax-wysiwyg-editor).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes Stackedit is pretty good; Is there any way to make the editor in Stackedit the editor in SE (so that you don't have to keep copying the information over from Stackedit)? But perhaps this is being a bit needy; otherwise Stackedit is a decent solution. Thanks for mentioning it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a userscript that I found in StackApps which was created partly by Antonio Vargas that enables side-by-side editing. This userscript adds a button to the editor toolbar ('Toggle Side-By-Side Editing') shown in the blue box in the image below so you can view the preview and markdown side by side when asking or answering a question or when editing an existing question or answer. You can also hide the preview as shown in the orange box.

To get this script first install Greasemonkey if you are using Firefox or Tampermonkey if using Chrome, and then click **[here](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/side-by-side-editing.user.js)**.

[image: Side by side editing]